# how to integrate angular template within MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api, angular7

i am trying to integrate angular 7 with MVC5 . everything is working fine but angular template is not rendering in my index.cshtml.

i have done the following things.

1. install angular using "npm install -g @angular/cli" and "ng new app"
2. after successful installation i added the App folder in my MVC project
3. added angular files into a script bundle in bundle.config.
4. add that bundle into the layout.cshtml
5. add  tag in my index.cstml

when i run the project my index.cshtml does not render the angular template.
i have tried different solution but nothing work. did i miss some steps to integrate it with mvc5?. i am using visual studio 2019 community edition. following is my code.

bundle.config:

`bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Script/Bundles")
               .Include(
                   "~/bundles/inline.*",
                   "~/bundles/polyfills.*",
                   "~/bundles/scripts.*",
                   "~/bundles/vendor.*",
                   "~/bundles/main.*"));
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Styles")
                .Include("~/bundles/styles.*"));`

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  AppComponent
 ],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  AppRoutingModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]})
export class AppModule { }
```

index.cshtml:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<app-root></app-root>
```

Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Hello World - ASP.NET MVC</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/Styles")
</head>
<body>
@Scripts.Render("~/Script/Bundles")

<main role="main" class="container">
    @RenderBody()
</main>
```

Comment: are there any errors loading the view? Have your tried moving your scrips underneath `<main>`? Also, did you do an `ng build` to get the correct output from angular build?

Comment: no error in the console when i use ng build in command prompt it successfully build the project and when  i run angular project using ng serve it show the component.html page correctly in the browser window. but when i try to access this on my index.cshtml it does not work . i also try to move scripts underneath "main" but it does not work.

Comment: are you sure you're loading the scripts from the correct place? Usually they are located in the `dist` folder, have you checked that they are being loaded

Comment: another problem i've encountered is that when bundles are minified, it doesn't play nicely with angular as the build are minified by `ng build --prod`, so I resorted to adding the scripts directly into the view and not using `Scripts.Render` etc

Comment: yes script is loading correctly i have checked it in browser window. i also put the script files directly but its also not working. is there any configuration change needed to run it on VS? on localhost:4200 angular project is running perfectly but in application port its not loading the template.

Comment: have you configured routing in angular? are you using `HashLocationStrategy`?

Comment: i have configured routing.

Comment: thanks Ric. i have resolved the problem! actually  "~/bundles/runtime.*" was missing. after adding this in bundle.config application starts rendering angular template.

Comment: Ah! Good spot, glad it's working